# sms: link with alphabetical parameters interpreted as numbers on Samsung Galaxy S7

Tags: javascript, android, html, sms, samsung-galaxy

I have a link on my website to open up a text with a new message. The following link works on most Android phones:

`sms:5555555555?body=JOIN`

But on the Galaxy S7, the ?body=JOIN parameter is interpreted to be a part of the phone number itself, as if the letters we input on a keypad. So the example above, would open up a new message to the phone number: `555555555526395646` and an empty message body.

I don't have an s7 myself so it's difficult to debug. Any ideas what else I can try to make it work as expected on the s7?

Comment: You could try installing Android Studio and emulating a S7 device to try your site in it.

Comment: I have a Galaxy S7 and I can't reproduce this behavior. Any more info?

Comment: @BenP. cannot reproduce? maybe then the OP must have some issue with his/her site...

Comment: try adding http://jquerymobile.com/ to your project

Answer (score 1):

Different platform wise it will work differently. check challenges section on this [link](http://thenewcode.com/856/Send-a-SMS-Text-From-A-Link)

For iOS same problem here and for android its partially support

Answer (score 0):

As Rajesh suggests, this will widely differ for different platforms, and sometimes for different version. This is the structure you would use for Android :

```
<a href="sms:/* Phone Number */?body=/* Body of the message */">Link</a>
```

And for iOS :

```
<a href="sms:/* Phone Number */&body=/* Body of the message */">Link</a>
```

Keep in mind that these formats can change (in your example the format works on most Android devices, but not on an S7; in other examples, the format was different for sending SMS in iOS 7 and iOS 8). Also, note that the app which handles the SMS URI can be changed on Android, and manufacturers take advantage of it (which may be what caused the malfunction on the S7 in the first place). So tweaking with exceptions can be a little hacky.

Otherwise, you could consider using an existing package like [sms](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sms) or a service like [Twilio](https://www.twilio.com/blog/2016/09/how-to-send-an-sms-with-node-js-using-twilio.html).

Answer (score 0):

Although I cannot reproduce the behaviour, here are some links from the [RFC's](https://www.ietf.org/rfc.html) addressing the [`sms:`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5724) and [`tel:`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3966) URI schemes.

Under [section 2.2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5724#section-2.2) of [RFC 5724 - URI Scheme for GSM Short Message Service](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5724) is the *formal definition* of the URI, which says that the `sms-recipient` (the phone number you want to send the sms to) must be equal to `telephone-subscriber` which is defined in [RFC 3966](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3966#page-4).

Although, your URI seems to work correctly on most of the devices (quirk? edge-case?), you must cross-check the format with the one described in the RFC to be sure that it's standards-compliant. Or maybe it's possible that it's a software/parser bug on the device itself! (not sure though...)